# Getting more characters inside matcher group than expected

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match the following string against the pattern:

```
String s  = "AAA|VY~1055~ ~~BCN~09/24/2012~";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\|VY\\~(.*)\\~").matcher(s);

if (m.find()) 
{
  String value = m.group(2);      
  System.out.print("value = " + value);
}
```

The output is:

```
value = 1055~ ~~BCN~09/24/2012
```

But I want this:

```
value = 1055
```

Why is it getting all the characters until the end of string?

I've read something about to consume to the end of string, and I've tried:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\|VY\\~(.*)\\~(.*)").matcher(s);
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\|VY\\~(.*)\\~.*").matcher(s);
```

But it doesn't work.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you need to escape `~`s in java regexes?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `*?` (reluctant) quantifier, which is lazy (stops matching as soon as possible).

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\|VY\\~(.*?)\\~").matcher(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to read about the [gready, reluctant and possessive quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) (need to scroll down a bit).